# Using f32 in a struct

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a `struct` that has an `f32` but I'm getting this error after trying to compare two of the same datatype:

> the trait `std::cmp::Eq` is not implemented for `f32`

Here is what I have tried:

```
#[derive(Eq)]
pub struct Document {
    pub score: f32,
}

impl PartialEq for Document {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Document) -> bool {
        self.score == other.score
    }
}

fn main() {

    let num: Document = Document { score: 1.0f32 };
    let num2: Document = Document { score: 1.0f32 };

    assert!(num == num2);

}
```

And here is the [Rust Play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23%5Bderive(Eq)%5D%0Apub%20struct%20Document%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20pub%20score%3A%20f32%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20PartialEq%20for%20Document%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20eq(%26self%2C%20other%3A%20%26Document)%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.score%20%3D%3D%20other.score%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20num%3A%20Document%20%3D%20Document%20%7B%20score%3A%201.0f32%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20num2%3A%20Document%20%3D%20Document%20%7B%20score%3A%201.0f32%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20assert!(num%20%3D%3D%20num2)%3B%0A%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0). Any idea what is going on?

Comment: "Any idea [...]" Yes. `f32` indeed does not implement `Eq` because floating point types do not provide a "pure" equality relationship. Do you really need your `Document` to implement `Eq`?

Comment: Please review what [floating point equality means](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

Comment: @E_net4 hmm, didn't know that. Yes, I have to implement `Eq` for that struct.